# How to trigger a bash script through http request?

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, command-line-interface, devops

There is a software that only runs on windows. This software has a command line interface which converts different file types. I want to trigger the commands of this software based on http requests made by other servers. I am not experienced with devops. I have only worked with nginx and apache for simple applications which use express.js or wordpress.

I want to believe that there is no need to have to setup a whole application just to proxy some http requests into command line. So I was hoping if there is some light weight software or way to execute bash scripts when I receive certain http requests.

Comment: Why is this having`docker` as one of its tags?

Comment: If you are familiar with Python, you can create a webserver using something like `FastAPI` or `Flask` to receive your HTTP requests. The endpoint can trigger a command line argument which can invoke a bash script.